# How do I stop my VIM background from being transparent in tmux where there is no text?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vim, tmux

I've been working on moving my development setup to a new Ubuntu based partition from Mac OS.

I'm currently having trouble getting the background to stay solid inside of tmux.

I have TERM set to xterm-256color in my .bashrc and vim works as intended outside of tmux. I have also aliased tmux to "tmux -2" and added

```
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
```

to my .tmux.conf.

My .vimrc contains:

```
set t_Co=256
set background=dark
color Tomorrow-Night
```

I suppose the best way to explain this is with images... Here is the intended look outside of tmux
(Tomorrow-Night colorscheme):

[image: VIM outside of tmux]

And here is what I am experiencing inside of tmux:

[image: VIM inside of tmux]

As you can see, the terminal background is bleeding through where there is no text.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just tried reproducing your setup on my machine and I get a similar problem with the background.

It seems setting TERM to `xterm-256color` in your `.bashrc` overrides `set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"` from tmux and that causes issues. This makes sense as `bash` is running inside tmux and its setting override those from tmux.

You can easily verify this by running `echo $TERM` in `bash` within `tmux`. With your current setup it will be `xterm-256color` which is a no-go as Tmux explicitly requires this to be set to `screen-256color`.

A quickfix to verify this theory is just removing or commenting out a line in your `.bashrc` where you set `TERM` and trying things out.

A proper solution would be to have something like this `.bashrc`:

```
[ -z "$TMUX" ] && export TERM="xterm-256color"
```

The above line will:

- set `TERM` to `xterm-256color` if bash is running standalone (no tmux)
- will not override `TERM` if running inside tmux